# Salesforce 1 notification for new task assignment from apex code

Tags: salesforce1-app, task-notifications

I have created a batchable class to query all opportunities which match some conditions and then creates a new related task for these opportunities using apex code.

But salesforce1 users didn't receive any push notification when the new task has been assigned to themselves - If I create a task manually, they still receive the notification.

Comment: Hi Hari, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The more details you provide, **particularly code you've written**, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer you'll find helpful.